# Msys fail to download angleproject package

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

Working with Msys2 x64.
For command

```
#  pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-{ffmpeg,libjpeg-turbo,lua51,64-angleproject-git}
```

Receive message as below:

```
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg-4.2.2-4 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo-2.0.4-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
error: target not found: mingw-w64-x86_64-64-angleproject-git
```

What may be cause of problem finding angleproject package?

Comment: Before started asking questions found Msys may be outdated. So before came here I made update by `# Pacman -Syu` and later `# Pacman -Su`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package was dropped in [55de8032](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/55de803278c97ac0d19253c2edefdf397cc18342) in June of 2019, probably because it was an unreasonable maintenance burden.

You're free to build it yourself.  The recipe was moved to [mingw-packages-dev](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages-dev/tree/master/mingw-w64-angleproject-git).  You can also check out the mingw-w64-angleproject-git recipe for Arch Linux on [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/?h=mingw-w64-angleproject) and in [the repository of the author](https://github.com/Martchus/PKGBUILDs/tree/master/angleproject/mingw-w64).

Comment: Can you help me to build from recipe? I have no idea how to start with.

Comment: Beware, it's not an easy task. Start by cloning https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages-dev, then go into `mingw-w64-angleproject-git` and try running `makepkg-mingw`. If it creates a package, congratulations, use `pacman -U *.pkg.*` to install it. If you see errors, you'll have to solve them somehow. I don't want to give much time to this package because I don't need it currently.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful